# date format configuration in dozer.xml

Tags: mapping, dozer, xml-configuration

I am using Dozer mapper to map Service objects to Value objects. I am mapping the date by means of the following:

```
<mapping date-format="dd-MM-yyyy">
  <class-a>MySo</class-a>
  <class-b>MyVO</class-b>
  <field>
    <a>dateStr</a>
    <b>dateObj</b>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

However, I need to specify the format for the date each time. Is there some other approach to map string date directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dozer.xml we can specify some default configuration.

for eg.

```
<configuration>
    <stop-on-errors>true</stop-on-errors>
    <date-format>dd-MM-yy</date-format>
    <wildcard>true</wildcard>
</configuration>
```

here is [Link](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/stringtodatemapping.html) to refer.